# Press-and-hold button in Mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile-safari

I've attached a Javascript event listener to a keyboard button so that on the desktop, when I press and hold the left arrow key, the javascript values change based on my keyboard's repeat rate. Is there anything I can create in Mobile Safari that would do something similar?

Answer (score 4):

not sure of what you want to achieve here, but as there is often no keyboard left arrow key involved when browsing through mobile safari, the best thing you could do is probably listen for touch events on a specific element that would represent a left arrow key.
[some Apple documentation about that here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

For example you could start a `setInterval` timer when you get a `touchstart` event, and stop it after a `touchend` event : http://jsfiddle.net/ZWtFK/